# How to find Graph that is not isomorphic?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I need to find Graph *G* with degree sequence *(5,5,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,2)* constructed with Havel Hakimi method, that will not be isomorphic with *G*. Is it even possible?

Comment: What is not isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: It is difficult to find a graph $G$ that is not isomorphic with $G$. I think you mean something else.

Comment: I think it is not possible to find isomorphic graph, But  I don't know why it is not possible ?.

Comment: I think you mean construct a graph. You can think of two graphs, namely $G$ and $G^{'}$ both with the same degree sequence but having different structural property. For eg: Graph $G$ can have no triangles while Graph $G^{'}$ should have one. Now, the Havel-Hakimi theorem just states that a degree sequence is simply graphical or not; that is if there's a graph representation of a degree sequence.

Comment: Are you asking for the number of non-isomorphic graphs with the given degree sequence?

Comment: Yes, non-isomorphic graphs with given degree sequence constructed by havel-hakimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Using the Havel-Hakimi Theorem we can build graph $H$. After some thought I came up with graph $G$, such that: $G \ncong H$. Why?

In graph $G$, we have: $v_{i}$ adjacent to two vertices of degree $2$ and a vertex of degree $5$, for $i = 1, 2$. Where as in graph $H$, we can clearly see that vertex $u_{2}$ doesn't have such a configuration.

Furthermore, note that both graphs have degree sequence; $S: 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2$.